# how to change multiple button image and conditions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uibutton

I am having two buttons in the table view cell, when I click the 1st button, background image changed to the selected image , at the same time my 2nd button image should not change when 1st button is selected. how can I do this process.

```
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button1.frame = CGRectMake(80, 27, 36, 36);
[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"l"ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 button1.tag = 1;
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button1];

  UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button2.frame = CGRectMake(160, 27, 36, 36);
[button2 setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"e"ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   button2.tag = 2;
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button2];


- (void)radiobtn:(UIButton *)button
{

}
```

These buttons are in table view cell,1st button selected image name = blue image. 
2nd button selected image name = red image. please help me i am new to IOS.

Comment: Use different button action methods for 2 buttons. You are using same button actions. In first button action change the background image of btn1.

Comment: @RJV can u help me in coding , please

Answer (score 1):

please use different selector and do the code in different function.For now you have used only a single method i.e . radiobtn:(UIButton *){}

Or if you want to keep the same selector then you can place a check of tags which button is clicked and perform the code accordingly

```
-(void)radiobtn:(UIButton *)button
{
     if(button.tag==1)
    {
    // perform the code when button 1 is clicked and change the images accordingly
    }
    else
    {
    // perform the code when button 2 is clicked 
    }
}
```

Comment: if ([button1 isSelected]) {
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"l.png"]
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"select");
     
        [button1 setSelected:NO];
    } else {
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lblue.png"]
                forState:UIControlStateSelected];
          NSLog(@"not select");
        [button1 setSelected:YES];
    }
i have tried this for  button 1 image is not changing why?

Comment: in place of setImage use setBackgroundImage..as you have use isSelected

Comment: don't use is selected. Just use the tag of buttons